# stack two columns into one (data.table) in r

Tags: r, data.table

i have the following data:

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 |

The result I want is:

| ID | C |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Comment: Take a look at the `tidyr` package and its `pivot_longer()` function: `df1 %>% pivot_longer(-ID, values_to = "C") %>% select(-name)` should do the trick.

Comment: `melt(df, 'ID')`

Comment: basically I have other columns in the input data, how can I specify the columns that I want to melt in this command *df1 %>% pivot_longer(-ID, values_to = "C") %>% select(-name)*?

Comment: Instead of deselecting columns you do not want to `pivot_longer()` (here: `-ID`, you can select them with `cols=c()`:
`df1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(A,B),  values_to = "C") %>% select(-name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this command to answer my question :

```
df1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(A,B),  values_to = "C") %>% 
        select(-name)
```

thanks to the previous comments by Martin Gal and Gnueghoidune

Answer (score 0):

The cdata package has transformation functions that pivot and unpivot with multiple variables. What I like about the package is the control table idea  that visually arranges the data in the form you want to see.

In this case, starting with a data frame `df`,

```
ID <- c(1, 2)
A <- c(4, 5)
B <- c(2, 3)
df <- data.table(ID, A, B)


# check the data 
df[]

#>   ID A B
#> 1  1 4 2
#> 2  2 5 3
```

Build a cdata control table. This is the basic element that allows you to unambiguously assign which data values go where. In this case, I use a new variable `from` to identify the columns from which values are taken and `C` is the new column with the desired values.

```
# build a control table
from <- c("col_A", "col_B")
C    <- c("A", "B")
control_table <- data.table(from, C)

# examine the result
control_table[]
#>     from C
#> 1: col_A A
#> 2: col_B B
```

With the control table ready, I can use `rowrecs_to_blocks()` from cdata to transform the data from row record (wide) form to block record (longer) form. The `ID` variable is repeated as many times as necessary to complete the block records.

```
# transform to block form
DT <- cdata::rowrecs_to_blocks(
  wideTable     = df, 
  controlTable  = control_table,
  columnsToCopy = c("ID"))
setDT(DT)

# examine the result
DT[]
#>    ID  from C
#> 1:  1 col_A 4
#> 2:  1 col_B 2
#> 3:  2 col_A 5
#> 4:  2 col_B 3
```

You can omit the `from` column, though by keeping it you can always recover the original data frame if you need to.

```
# omit the from column
DT[, from := NULL]
DT
#>    ID C
#> 1:  1 4
#> 2:  1 2
#> 3:  2 5
#> 4:  2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` where `melt` is the `dplyr`'s equivalent of `pivot_longer`

```
dt <- data.table(ID = 1:2, A = 4:5, B = 2:3)

dt <- melt(dt, measure.vars = c("A", "B"), value.name = "C")
dt[, variable := NULL]
setorder(dt, ID) # to get the same order as your desired output

dt
#    ID C
# 1:  1 4
# 2:  1 2
# 3:  2 5
# 4:  2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `by`.

```
DT[, .(C = c(A, B)), by = ID]
#       ID     C
#    <int> <int>
# 1:     1     4
# 2:     1     2
# 3:     2     5
# 4:     2     3
```

Reproducible data

```r
DT = data.table(ID = 1:2, A = 4:5, B = 2:3)
```